# How to preserve "expanded" state of additional form fields with JavaScript when clicking the back button in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, state, back

I have a form that has two radio buttons. When one of the radio buttons is clicked, JavaScript is used to set a group of sub-fields using display: block.

How can I make it so the selected radio button and sub-fields will expand when clicking the back button in IE? This issue does not occur in Webkit or Firefox.

It needs to work with plain JavaScript, so no jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

One popular methods is to use a **URL-hash** to represent the UI state. As the UI changes, you build up a hash:

```
document.location.hash = "R1=true;R2=false"
```

When you re-load the page, look at the hash and use JavaScript to set the relevant UI elements. How you represent your elements is up to you.